# Improve performance of slow query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am running a report with below query and it takes about 40 sec in Visual studio but over 1min 15 sec in report server

Report has 4 datasets and 3 parameters.

```
QUERY:

SELECT PRPH_ML1,
       Section,
       AgeBand,
       TermTimeWeekNo,
       Sum(Mins_Poss) AS Mins_Poss,
       Sum(Mins_Att)  AS Mins_Att,
       Sum(Mins_Late) AS Mins_Late,
       REGT_Provision_Code,
       PRPH_Title,
       REGH_Class_Register,
       REGH_Register_Title,
       Section_Name,
       Register_Day,
       REGH_ISN,
       PRPH_ISN,
       REGH_Start_Time
FROM   CurrentAttendance
WHERE  ( CourseType IN ( @CourseType ) )
       AND ( REGT_Year = @Year )
       AND ( AgeBand IN ( @AgeBand ) )
GROUP  BY PRPH_ML1,
          Section,
          AgeBand,
          TermTimeWeekNo,
          REGT_Provision_Code,
          PRPH_Title,
          REGH_Class_Register,
          REGH_Register_Title,
          Section_Name,
          Register_Day,
          REGH_ISN,
          PRPH_ISN,
          REGH_Start_Time

VIEW:

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_currentattendance_new]
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      ---delete existing warehouse table------------------------------
      IF Object_id('dbo.CurrentAttendance', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE dbo.CurrentAttendance;

      --------Create New Table------------------------------------------------
      ---Weeks----------------------------------------------------------------
      WITH weeks
           AS (SELECT VDC_week_no,
                      VDC_cal_year,
                      Min(VDC_day_date) AS WeekCommence
               FROM   sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
               WHERE  VDC_avail = 'T'
               GROUP  BY VDC_week_no,
                         VDC_cal_year),
           ---TTWeeks--------------------------------------------------------------
           TTWeeks
           AS (SELECT VDC_Cal_Year              AS REMSYear,
                      [VDC_week_no]             AS WholeYearWeekNo,
                      WeekCommence,
                      Row_number()
                        OVER(
                          PARTITION BY vdc_cal_year
                          ORDER BY VDC_week_no) AS TermTimeWeekNo
               FROM   weeks)
      ---Main---------------------------------------------------------------------
      SELECT STYR_Primary_Programme        AS PrimaryProgramme,
             Rtrim(h2.PRPH_Title)          AS PRPH_Title,
             Rtrim(h2.PRPH_ML1)            AS PRPH_ML1,
             Rtrim(h2.PRPH_ML2)            AS Section,
             CASE
               WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug < 16 THEN '1416'
               WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug < 19 THEN '1618'
               ELSE '19+'
             END                           AgeBand,
             rg.REGT_Year                  AS RegYear,
             q.GNCD_Description            AS [Curriculum Area],
             q.GNCD_Description            AS Section_Name,
             LEFT(q.GNCD_Description, 3)   AS Dept,
             Rtrim(rg.REGT_Provision_Code) AS REGT_Provision_Code,
             rg.REGT_Student_ID            AS Student_ID,
             STEN_Funding_Stream           AS FundingStream,
             rs.REGS_Session_No            AS RegSession,
             Rtrim(rh.REGH_Class_Register) AS Class_Register,
             Rtrim(rh.REGH_Register_Title) AS Register_Title,
             rh.REGH_Day                   AS ReghDay,
             CASE
               WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '1' THEN 'Sunday'
               WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '2' THEN 'Monday'
               WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '3' THEN 'Tuesday'
               WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
               WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '5' THEN 'Thursday'
               WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '6' THEN 'Friday'
               WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '7' THEN 'Saturday'
             END                           AS Register_Day,
             rh.[REGH_Start_Time]          AS StartTime,
             rh.[REGH_End_Time]            AS EndTime,
             CASE
               WHEN ( rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '27%'
                       OR rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'MA27%'
                       OR rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'FS%' ) THEN 'FunctionalSkill'
               WHEN rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '16%' THEN 'GCSE'
               WHEN rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/F%'
                     OR rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/D%'
                     OR rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/E%'
                     OR rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/X%' THEN 'Main'
               ELSE 'Addition'
             END                           AS CourseType,
             CASE
               WHEN Isnull(ra.RGAT_Present, 'X') IN ( 'N', 'Y', 'X' )
                    AND rs.REGS_Session_Date < Getdate() THEN rs.REGS_Duration - Isnull(rd.REGD_Mins_Late, 0)
               ELSE 0
             END                           AS Mins_Poss,
             CASE
               WHEN Isnull(ra.RGAT_Present, 'X') = 'Y'
                    AND rs.REGS_Session_Date < Getdate() THEN rs.REGS_Duration - rd.REGD_Mins_Late
               ELSE 0
             END                           AS Mins_Att,
             CASE
               WHEN ra.RGAT_Present = 'Y'
                    AND rs.REGS_Session_Date < Getdate() THEN rd.REGD_Mins_Late
               ELSE 0
             END                           AS Mins_Late,
             rs.[REGS_Session_Date]        AS Session_Date,
             TermTimeWeekNo                AS TermTimeWeekNo,
             rh.REGH_ISN                   AS REGHISN,
             h2.PRPH_ISN                   AS PRPHISN,
             st.STUD_Surname               AS Surname,
             st.STUD_Forename_1            AS Forename,
             rd.REGD_Attendance_Mark       AS AttendanceMark,
             rg.REGT_start_date            AS Startdate,
             rg.REGT_End_date              AS Enddate,
             WeekCommence                  AS WeekStart
      INTO   CurrentAttendance
      FROM   sql10.ng.dbo.REGTrgstudt rg
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.REGSrgsessn rs
                     ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rs.REGS_REGH_ISN
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender dc
                     ON rs.REGS_Session_Date = dc.VDC_day_date
             INNER JOIN TTWeeks
                     ON rg.REGT_year = TTWeeks.REMSYear
                        AND dc.VDC_week_no = WholeYearWeekNo
                        AND dc.VDC_cal_year = REMSYear
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.REGHrghdr rh
                     ON rh.REGH_ISN = rg.REGT_REGH_ISN
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader h
                     ON REGT_Provision_Code = h.PRPH_Code
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STEN
                     ON STEN_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID
                        AND STEN_Provision_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code
                        AND STEN_Provision_Instance = rg.REGT_Provision_Instance
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STYRstudentYR s
                     ON s.STYR_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID
                        AND s.STYR_Year = rg.REGT_Year
             LEFT JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader h2
                    ON h2.prph_code = s.STYR_Primary_Programme
             INNER JOIN (SELECT ACYR_College_Year
                         FROM   sql10.ng.dbo.ACYR
                         WHERE  ( ACYR_ENR_PY_CY_NY IN ( 'CY' ) )) AS SUB
                     ON rg.REGT_Year = SUB.ACYR_College_Year
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STUDStudent st
                     ON s.STYR_Student_ID = st.STUD_Student_ID
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.REGDropin rd
                     ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rd.REGD_REGH_ISN
                        AND rg.REGT_Student_ID = rd.REGD_Student_ID
                        AND rd.REGD_Session_No = rs.REGS_Session_No
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.RGATAttendance ra
                     ON REGD_Attendance_Mark = ra.RGAT_Attendance_Code
             INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance AS pit
                     ON pit.PRPI_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code
                        AND pit.prpi_instance = rg.REGT_Provision_Instance
             INNER JOIN (SELECT GNCD_General_Code,
                                GNCD_Description
                         FROM   sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes
                         WHERE  ( GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2' )) AS q
                     ON q.GNCD_General_Code = Rtrim(h2.PRPH_ML2)
  END
```

Can you suggest some tips to improve performance.

Comment: What are the indexed fields of CurrentAttendance?

Comment: A slight side track...you have things like "CourseType IN ( @CourseType )" This is NOT going to find multiple values if you pass in a delimited list of courses. It is in fact the same as "CourseType = @CourseType". If you want multiple values you need to find another way to do this. Also, you might take a look at this for naming. The sp_ prefix is not a good way to name your procedures. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: You also have some potential concurrency issues when you drop a table in a procedure and then fill it again. If you have two users running this procedure it is possible you could have all sort of strange results.

Comment: Question fit here [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) better

Comment: This would be on-topic at Code Review, however if the OP decides to post there, they will want to explain in plain English, in addition to the code, what this query is meant to achieve, and a title that reflects that.

Comment: Do wee need all the tables involved in the process? it seems like we have a lot of JOIN statements
have you checked if indexed and statistics are updated?
why dont you create a #temp table and at the end output all the result in there? it might happen an error when another user tries to run the report as every time the proc is executed is dropping and creating the tables

Comment: My practice 1 - Create a temp table to store output from this query, update temp table with some trigger. 2 - declare a temp table same as 1st but store this temp table output with session etc. By reading datasource from session, report will displayed in less than 5 second.

Comment: @Dan there are no indexes on table